# Why am I getting the following error in my code: TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, dictionary, integer

```py
b,e=dict(),dict()
mx=0
for _ in range(int(input())):
    a,b,c=list(map(int,input().split()))
    b[a]=c;e[b]=c #cause of error
    mx=max(mx,b)
ans,cur=0,0
for j in range(b):
    if i in b:cur+=b[i]
    ans=max(ans,cur)
    if i in e:cur-=e[i]
print(max(ans,cur))
```

Here's a sample input:

```
5
4 8 2
5 12 7
1 3 3
10 16 3
17 18 6
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this error. What's the problem with assigning items to dictionaries using this fashion?

Comment: Because `b` is now an int. You `map`ped it to an int in the previous line. Check output of `print(type(b))`.

Comment: Use a different variable for the dicts. And name them better to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2):

this problem comes for the same name in your program "b". In line no 1 & 4. and also second for loop where j is in for loop but you used i

```
dic,e=dict(),dict()
mx=0
for _ in range(int(input())):
    a,b,c=list(map(int,input().split()))
    dic[a]=c;e[b]=c #cause of error
    mx=max(mx,b)
ans,cur=0,0
for j in range(b):
    if j in dic:cur+=dic[j]
    ans=max(ans,cur)
    if j in e:cur-=e[j]
print(max(ans,cur))

output:
5
4 8 2
5 12 7
1 3 3
10 16 3
17 18 6
10
```

use this code. I think it solve your problem